# what are the chances of a ring surviving in an explosion

Tags: explosions

There is a magic ring which was given to Sifar (a prince).  Later there was an battle on his castle and when he was running for shelter he got killed in a magic explosion which landed 12 feet away (on the side which the ring was not on).  The explosion is about the same as powerful as twenty  pounds of gunpowder in a metal flask.  What are the chances that the ring survived.

Comment: As it is a magic ring, is there any magical feature that protect it? and what is it made of?

Comment: The ring would most certainly survive. Why wouldn't it? Ordinary rings most usually are not damaged by eplosions which kill or injure the wearer.

Comment: @Emilio Linano the magic will not protect the ring its use is irreverent to the question I should have said that in my question and the ring is made out of stone with bits of steel in it so no gold

Comment: What are the chances? I would say either 0% (you don't want it to) or 100% (you want it to). I fail to see how this is anything other than an element of plot for your story, and so is [off-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 12):

Explosions are funny things.  I think even a common ring should easily survive the Explosion.  Stuff that comes after, maybe not so much

Lets start by ignoring the magic aspect of the ring, because that makes it too easy

As an EMT (a long time ago) we learned some about things that go boom and what to look for as a mechanism of injury.  Explosions do damage with 3 mechanisms.  The first is the pressure wave.  Second is heat, if the explosive material throws a lot of heat.  Third is Flying Debris.

Take them in order.  Pressure, the equations are complicated but the short form is that the further away you are, the less pressure, and it's a logarithmic equation, so the drop off is really sharp over distance.  from 20 feet away, there might be enough of a pressure wave to dent or maybe scar the surface of the ring, but not enough to destroy it.  That is given that your comparison is a 20lb black powder bomb.

Heat is more problematic for a ring.  If the bomb sets some surrounding wood structure on fire, and it's the right kind of wood and there was enough of it, the resulting fire might get hot enough in a small area to melt the gold of the ring.  Conditions would have to be just right, though.  If the prince's hand flies out the window the ring survives, if it bounces off the wall and lands in the middle of the fire, well, there goes the ring.  The results depend entirely on narrative convenience.

Finally the debris.  Again we have to rely on narrative convenience.  if the explosion knocks loose a multi-ton block on top of the prince, the ring could very well get squished. Maybe a decorative war axe is flung off the wall and splits the ring in two.  Unlikely, but possible.

There are tons of stories about how everything in a blast radius gets mangled except for that one tiny flower, or how a guy survived because he was shielded from the blast by an umbrella.  These stories are mostly apocryphal, but they are usually believable.

Explosions are funny things

Comment: I upvote this and won't add an answer; because I agree. The ring is plausibly shielded and protected from shock, heat, **and** debris by the body of the wearer, and its own composition: a shock wave does not affect metal much if it is as thick as my own wedding band. The body of the prince can fall on top of the ring; and even protect it from a great deal of fire in the aftermath; which probably would not get hot enough to melt gold anyway (rings are seldom pure gold, that is too soft, so it is more likely 22kt gold alloy; with a melting point of about 1945F). Ring survival is very plausible.

Comment: I would also add that the ring won't deform from the shockwave unless the shockwave's pressure exceeds the yield strength of the ring's material... so the odds of it breaking is low.

Comment: I agree, but my gut feeling is that the ring is **very** likely to survive, unless it was directly hit be a fragment of the "shell casing" or a secondary fragment of something hard. Human bodies are much more fragile than rings, magical or not. It is also small, so square-cube goes in it's favor. It would be a freak accident which destroys the ring.

Comment: That's why I brought up Narrative Convenience if destruction of the ring is required.  It's *possible* that the ring could be destroyed.  just not all that likely.

Comment: @PaulTIKI he magic will not protect the ring its use is irreverent to the question I should have said that in my question and the ring is made out of stone with bits of steel in it so no gold

Comment: That would make it even less likely to be destroyed by fire.  It might be more susceptible shock or debris as the stone might makie it more brittle, but it won't change things too much